# AIX script for file information

Tags: shell, unix, awk, scripting, aix

I have a file, in AIX server, with multiple record entries in below format

```
 Name(ABC XYZ)                              Gender(Male)
 AGE(26)                    BDay(1990-12-09)
```

My problem is I want to extract the name and the b'day from the file for all the records. I am trying to list it like below:

```
 ABC XYZ  1990-12-09
```

Can someone please help me with the scripting

Comment: what have you tried? Is each record really on 2 lines? or is the data all on one line. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
awk -F"[()]" '/Name/ && /Gender/{name=$2} /BDay/{print name,$4}' file.txt
```

That says... *"treat opening and closing parentheses as field separators. If you see a line go by that contains `Name` and `Gender`, save the second field in the variable `name`. If you see a line go by that contains the word `Bday`, print out the last name you saw and also the fourth field on the current line."*